# Sinch :: Delegate method "DidReceiveIncomingCall" not called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, voip, sinch

I am working on voice call application using sinch v3.9.8 SDK.

Delegate method "DidReceiveIncomingCall" is not called for incoming call while app is in background or is force closed  by user while calling from **iPhone 6(IOS 10.0.2) to iPhone 5(IOS 9.3.5).**
This is working fine while calling from iPhone 6 to iPhone 5.
I am getting notification for incoming call

**I used below code to initialize SinchClient**

```
_client.delegate = self;

_client.callClient.delegate = self;

[_client setSupportCalling:YES];
[_client enableManagedPushNotifications];

[_client setSupportActiveConnectionInBackground:NO];
[_client setSupportPushNotifications:YES];

[_client start];

// Start listening for incoming events (calls and messages).
[_client startListeningOnActiveConnection];
```

**I used below code to initialize managePush**

```
self.push = [Sinch managedPushWithAPSEnvironment:SINAPSEnvironmentAutomatic];
self.push.delegate = self;
[self.push setDesiredPushTypeAutomatically];
```

**Previously this both cases working fine.**

Answer (score 0):

dont use [_client setSupportPushNotifications:YES]; and [_client enableManagedPushNotifications]; togethe, the latter is for us to manage push, the former is when you want to handle push your self with your own push server

Comment: there is no method/property declaration for "setSupportManagedPush".i already use enableManagedPushNotifications

Comment: you should set  [_client setSupportPushNotifications:NO]; that method is for when you want to handle all push your self. What version of the SDK are you using?